# API for Asus 1005pe control backlight programmably?

Tags: c++, api, intel, eeepc, backlight

I'm using VS2008, my OS is Win7.
I tried WinAPI `IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_SUPPORTED_BRIGHTNESS` on my netbook. I can retrive a correct the LCD handle, but `DeviceIoControl` returns 0. I haven't found any APIs for GMA 3150 either.

Answer (score 1):

small example:
http://davidxl.blogspot.com/2010/07/controla-el-nivel-de-backlight-de-una.html

Comment: elaborate answer..and give him the clear what would be the problem..! then give suggestive links..